# Display fetch results jsp and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Hie Everyone.

First I would like to express my special thanks of gratitude to @Biznet for pointing out Java naming conventions violations in my previous post and walking me through my previous attempts .Many thanks!!!.

I have been working on hibernate parameter query . The outcome is to display fetched results based on passed string from search box . Example search for D the result will display Dan, Dennis ,Dorothy .The same with A,F or S.

The current obstacle  my jsp page is not displaying anything and no error on server side  Wild-fly .The page is loading and nothing is being displayed .I have tried to swap A%% parameter to A% ,still nothing is shown.  Here is my code :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="author_id")
private int id;

@Column(name="author_name")
private String author_Name;  
  getters and setters 


DAOImpl

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Author> getAuthors(){
Session currentSession =    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();


String searchString="A%%";
Query<Author> theQuery = 
currentSession.createQuery("select a"+
"from Author a"+  
"where a.author_Name like searchString",Author.class);
 theQuery.setParameter("searchString",searchString+"%");  
List<Author> authors = theQuery.getResultList();
    return authors;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String listAuthors(Model theModel) {
List<Author> theAuthors = authorDAO.getAuthors();       
    theModel.addAttribute("authors", theAuthors);
    return "list-authors";



list-authors.jsp
           <th>Author Name</th>
        <c:forEach var="tempAuthor" items="${author}">              <td>${tempAuthor.author_Name}
```

Comment: I have solved the problem after exhaustive research specifically http://www.codejava.net knowledge base .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem after exhaustive research specifically http://www.codejava.net knowledge base .

```
@Transactional
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")   
 //Passed parameter name in my method to be called by controller class    
  public List<Author> getAuthors(String name) {
  Session tsession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();                 
  String hql = "from Author where author_name like :keyword";
  Query query = tsession.createQuery(hql);
  query.setParameter("keyword", "%" + name + "%");            
  List<Author>authors =query.getResultList();          
   return authors;



@RequestMapping("/processForm")
//The controller will forward method call to DAO class 
public String getAuthors(@RequestParam(name = "text") String keyword, Model thModel) {  
   //The  DAO method forward the request using keyword      
      List<Author>authors=authorDao.getAuthors(keyword);    
      thModel.addAttribute("author", authors);      
//The selected column is displayed in jsp based on keyed string.      
 return "results";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `:` before parameter name `searchString` in your case i HSQL. `:name` is how you define named query parameters in HSQL

Comment: True and my controller was not passing anything .So I made several alterations in my DAO and Controller.